# why does openmp give warning when single block is enclosed in section block

Tags: c, openmp

I have a single block enclosed in a sections block like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

int nthreads, tid;

/* Fork a team of threads giving them their own copies of variables */
#pragma omp parallel private(tid) 
{

#pragma omp sections
{


#pragma omp section
{
printf("First section %d \n" , tid);
}

#pragma omp section
{


#pragma omp single
{
printf("Second Section block %d \n" , tid);
}

}

}

}  /* All threads join master thread and disband */

printf("Outside parallel block \n");


}
```

When i compile this code the compiler gives the following warning

work-sharing region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing, critical, ordered or master region

Why is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you this warning because you have an openmp single region nested inside an openmp sections region without an openmp parallel region nested between them.

This is known as a closely nested region.

In C, the worksharing constructs are for, sections, and single.

For further information see the [OpenMP Specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec30.pdf) or see [Intel's Documentation on Improper nesting of OpenMP* constructs](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/ptref/index.htm#pt_reference/references/sc_omp_global_nesting.htm).

In order to have the code compile cleanly, try replacing your `#pragma omp sections` with `#pragma omp parallel sections`
or enclosing `#pragma omp sections` with `#pragma omp parallel`.

See [Guide into OpenMP: Easy multithreading programming for C++](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/) for more information and examples.